# Accessing Mainfame SDSF thru Java API

Tags: java, mainframe, zos

My JavaFX application submits Z/OS jobs and gets details thru FTP using filetyp=JES command.

Recently i came to know about SDSF API thru which i can access the SDSF data instead of using FTP. If this API could replace the FTP job submission, i will get a better control of the Job submission process in the Application.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.isfa500/javapl.htm

But i could not get an example on how to code authentication and access SDSF API to get the job details. If someone has link to example Java program to Access SDSF API, please share

Comment: Well, you need your machine to be running at least z/OS 2.1, then you (or your boss, or his boss) need to talk to the technical staff to see about setting this up, with the authorisation. No-one from the internet can give you anything which will "work" at your site.

Comment: Thank you!! Just checked the version, we got Z/OS 1.13 :(  So, i got to stick to my ftp method till the upgrade. It might not happen too..

Comment: Is there any other way i can access jobs from Java? FTP method gives me less control and also the JESINTERFACELEVEL is set to 1. so, i am getting little information on the executed jobs. Especially missing the return codes in the job data which makes handling of the jobs more complex

Comment: JESINTERFACELEVEL is either due to security (which will make it more difficult to get it changed) or ignorance (where it will be easier, just don't jam it in their faces). Probably best to approach the technical people for them to see if they can give you what you need and for you to see if there are things you can live without. As well as security, they won't want 50,000 JES commands a second coming just because you can do it. You have to discuss exactly what you want and get it agreed and methods acceptable to both, then stick to it.

Comment: Thanks Bill!..I am just a small part of the big service provider company. I have no link to the technical people in the client side. Also, my application is to automate my own testing and learning :) So even if i ask someone, the chances are very less for a change in the system property for my ID. I want to use effectively to whatever access i have now. If i am not authorized for any operation then looking for an alternative approach..

Comment: If you are not authorised, that is it. There is no way around that. Whatever way you access the Mainframe has to be authorised. If you attempt anyone's suggestions, it will look like you are trying to get unauthorised access, which will look bad. No one knows what software the site has for access, and even then you'd need authorisation. There are no shortcuts or suck-it-and-see.

Comment: I have access to mainframe with JESINTERFACELEVEL =1 and will stick to the same FTP method as of now. Yes.. I don't want to do unauthorized things. Just came across SDSF API and thought it could give me more information on the jobs.. But our site does not have it.. :(